# Entity Framework: HasDefaultValueSql("getutcdate()").ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); not working as expected

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I configure my model as follows:

```
public class CampaignConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Campaign>
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Campaign> builder)
    {
        builder.HasIndex(new[] { "Name", "StateId" }).IsUnique();
        builder.Property(b => b.Created).HasDefaultValueSql("getutcdate()").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }
}
```

I then run the following code (xUnit test):

```
        var daveForPres = new Campaign
        {
            Name = "  Dave for President  ",
            State = colorado
        };
        // the constructor set the Created to now - honk that up before the save.
        daveForPres.SetPrivatePropertyValue("Created", new DateTime(1955, 09, 26));

        context.Campaigns.Add(daveForPres);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

And when I look in the database (via SSRS), the Created date is set to 1955-09-26.

Why is it using the value in my model object? It's supposed to be ignoring that.

Comment: Why should it ignore the value you provide? The SQL default value is meant to be **only** applied if no explicit value is provided - I think this is "works as designed"

Comment: @marc_s So that means I would have to set that property to null for it to not overwrite? Or is null considered a valid value and that would also overwrite? And in that case, what does ValueGeneratedOnAdd() mean/do? I read that to say that the DB is handling it and so don't overwrite it.

Comment: Basically just don't set that propert to any value at all - and let the database handle setting the defined SQL default when it adds the row.

Comment: @marc_s Ok, I'm not understanding something. I need that property in my model class, both so that column is put in the database and so I can read it in my code. I can make it a nullable DateTime (prefer not since it's never null) but null, default value, etc. - for any of those, it has a value. How do I not set it to "not any value at all?"

Comment: Just do the `daveForPres` as you have it - and just **do not** call the `SetPrivateProperty` method after that - just leave the `Created` property "unset" - then call `.SaveChanges` - seems to work just fine for me, anyway - and the SQL default is in fact applied

Comment: @marc_s My concern is when I update the record a week later, that it will then overwrite with the datetime of that day. I need to know what is going on and is supposed to go on with ValueGeneratedOnAdd(). I'll ask over on the Microsoft forum - they may have a resource who knows for sure.

Comment: David - should not happen, since if you load the record a week later, it **will** have a valid value for `Created` and if you store it back, then a valid value already exists and the default won't be applied

Comment: @marc_s Fair point on it just roundtripping the value back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the MSDN forum:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1191128/hasdefaultvaluesql(getutcdate())-valuegeneratedona)

```
modelBuilder.Property(b => b.Created).HasDefaultValueSql("getutcdate()").ValueGeneratedOnAdd().Metadata.SetBeforeSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);
```